# Can the Encoding API decode a Stream/noncontinuous bytes?

Tags: c#, character-encoding, .net-standard

Usually we can get a `string` from a `byte[]` using something like

```
var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

However, I am having this problem: my input is an `IEnumerable<byte[]> bytes` (implementation can be any structure of my choice). It is not guaranteed a character is within a `byte[]` (for example, a 2-byte UTF8 char can have its 1st byte in bytes[1][length - 1] and its 2nd byte in bytes[2][0]).

Is there anyway to decode them without merging/copying all the array together? **UTF8 is main focus** but it is better if other Encoding can be supported. If there is no other solution, I think implementing my own UTF8 reading would be the way.

I plan to stream them using a `MemoryStream`, however Encoding cannot work on `Stream`, just `byte[]`. If merged together, the potential result array may be very large (up to 4GB in `List<byte[]>` already).

I am using .NET Standard 2.0. I wish I could use 2.1 (as it is not released yet) and using `Span<byte[]>`, would be perfect for my case!

Comment: [`MemoryStream.WriteAsync` is always synchronous](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs,7c6cbea58a012b83). There's no point in calling it ever, just use `MemoryStream.Write` and save some await overhead. Likewise `StreamReader.ReadToEndAsync` will call `MemoryStream.ReadAsync`, [which is synchronous](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs,2142088b3533a169). Using `await` here is only adding completely unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. However, we do have principles that we do not depend on implementation. In this case, we simply trust the implementation is doing what is right, as it is not too critical (speed is currently not a problem, but memory space).

Comment: Another way of looking at this: you have a choice between the synchronous and the asynchronous APIs. Always blindly taking one or the other is silly - you need to weight them up for each situation. Here, it's obvious (even without delving into the implementation) that synchronously copying a few bytes is *always* going to be faster than doing it asynchronously - either the implementation will spin up a whole new thread (100x slowdown at least), or it will do a synchronous copy but pretend it's asynchronous (still overhead). Blindly using async != trusting the implementation

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer.

Comment: @TomBlodget I have just done that. While it is good, I think canton7's solution works better in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Encoding` class can't deal with that directly, but the [`Decoder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.decoder?view=netframework-4.7.2) returned from [`Encoding.GetDecoder()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getdecoder?view=netframework-4.7.2) can (indeed, that's its entire reason for existing). `StreamReader` uses a `Decoder` internally.

It's slightly fiddly to work with though, as it needs to populate a `char[]`, rather than returning a `string` (`Encoding.GetString()` and `StreamReader` normally handle the business of populating the `char[]`).

The problem with using a `MemoryStream` is that you're copying all of the bytes from one array to another, for no gain. If all of your buffers are the same length, you can do this:

```
var decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
// +1 in case it includes a work-in-progress char from the previous buffer
char[] chars = decoder.GetMaxCharCount(bufferSize) + 1;
foreach (var byteSegment in bytes)
{
    int numChars = decoder.GetChars(byteSegment, 0, byteSegment.Length, chars, 0);
    Debug.WriteLine(new string(chars, 0, numChars));
}
```

If the buffers have different lengths:

```
var decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
char[] chars = Array.Empty<char>();
foreach (var byteSegment in bytes)
{
    // +1 in case it includes a work-in-progress char from the previous buffer
    int charsMinSize = decoder.GetMaxCharCount(bufferSize) + 1;
    if (chars.Length < charsMinSize)
        chars = new char[charsMinSize];
    int numChars = decoder.GetChars(byteSegment, 0, byteSegment.Length, chars, 0);
    Debug.WriteLine(new string(chars, 0, numChars));
}
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks a lot, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> however Encoding cannot work on Stream, just byte[].

Correct but a `StreamReader : TextReader` can be linked to a Stream.

So just create that MemoryStream, push bytes in on one end and use ReadLine() on the other. I must say I have never tried that.

Comment: Funny I am writing a custom StreamReader implementation because my business logic requires very weird reading pattern and I totally forgot about StreamReader itself! Yes it should work, I will try it now and post the result soon.

Comment: Yes it works! I have added the code segment in my question, please copy it over your answer and I will mark it :) EDIT: turned out what I needed to write is a custom Stream, not custom StreamReader!

Comment: You can post your code as a self-answer. But your quick-test won't deal with broken characters, do point that out.

Comment: And yes, the MemoryStream only has 1 Position so you can't read/write it like a queue. A petty sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Working code based on Henk's answer using `StreamReader`:

```
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
        {
            foreach (var byteSegment in bytes)
            {
                memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                await memoryStream.WriteAsync(byteSegment, 0, byteSegment.Length);
                memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                Debug.WriteLine(await reader.ReadToEndAsync());
            }
        }
    }
```